# Mozilla addon keyword search through Web Page(content)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I need to do keyword search in Loaded web page. Is there any good way other than get all web site HTMl and search.

Comment: isn't Ctrl+F suffice for your problem?

Comment: Hi I need to this in Programmatic. Inside the my addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching the HTML content, you could try searching just the text content. Maybe use the string `content.document.body.textContent` or something like that?